# Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.QueryString' cannot be used like a method

Tags: asp.net

I want to take the id by the querystring.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    int id=Request.QueryString("id");          
}
```

And here is where I want to get its value from the query:

[image: this]

[image: this]

Comment: whats your question? whats your code? please edit your question Hamzah

Comment: i am trying to take an id from the query on pageload. The page is (otherusers.aspx) and i have sent an id in it like (otheruser.aspx?id=5). i want to request this id and take its value.

Comment: add this detail to yyour question...your question must be cleard if you wanted to get best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
int id=Request.QueryString["id"];
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) i am new to this.

Comment: No problem, we all got to learn. Please mark the answer as useful.